# Django inline formset with child of a child

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have three models:

1. `Variable`, which has `Group` as a foreign key
2. `Group`, which has `Set` as a foreign key
3. `Set`

I want to create a form that lets user create a new Set based on existing Set. Only things that user is able to modify are the Set name and Variable values.

[This](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1246/) has given me an idea of using `inlineformset_factory` to access models' children. Sadly, all the examples I found go only one layer down.

Is there any way to access the Variables of a Set through `inlineformset_factory`?

If not - what is a good way to accomplish my goal?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, it is not worth hacking the existing `inlineformset_factory` to achieve much beyond what it is meant to do.

You are better off writing a custom view with the qs you want to use and create unique ids for each form element, to identify its parent.